# Calculating algorithm complexity by counting steps

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Trying to calculate the big o of the function by counting the steps. I think those are how to count each step by following how they did it in the examples, but not sure how to calculate the total.

```
int function (int n){
   int count = 0;                              // 1 step
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)              // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
         for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)           // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
            for (int m = 0; m <= n; m++)       // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
               count++;                        // 1 step
  return count;                                // 1 step
}
```

I want to say this function is O(n^2), but I dont understand how that was calculated.

Examples I've been looking at

```
int func1 (int n){
       int sum = 0;                                // 1 step
       for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
          sum += i;                                // 1 step
       return sum;                                 // 1 step
}                                                  //total steps: 4 + 3n
```

and

```
int func2 (int n){
           int sum = 0;                                // 1 step
           for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
              for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)             // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
                  sum ++;                              // 1 step
           for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)                // 1 + 1 + n * (2 steps)
               sum--;                                  // 1 step
           return sum;                                 // 1 step
    }      
                                                       //total steps: 3n^2 + 7n + 6
```

Comment: Your first algorithm is O(n^4) - there are 4 nested loops between 0 and n, therefore the number of steps is proportional to n^4. The second example is O(n) and third example is O(n^2) - you have two nested loops from 0 to n

Answer (score 2):

What you've just proposed here are quite simple examples.
In my opinion you just need to understand how the complexity in a cycle works, in order to understand your examples.

*In short* (*very briefly*) a cycle has to be considered in [asymptotic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) as following:

```
loop (condition) :
  // loop body
end loop
```

- The `condition` of the loop should tell you how many times the loop will be executed *compared to the **size of the input***.
- The complexity of the body (you can consider the body as an sub-function and compute the complexity as well) has to be multiplied by the complexity of the loop.

The reason is quite intuitive: what you have in the body will be executed repetitively until the condition is verified, that is the number of times the loop (and so the body) will be executed.

---

Just some example:

```
// Array linear assignment
std::vector<int> array(SIZE_ARRAY);

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_ARRAY; ++i) {
  array[i] = i;
}
```

Let's analyse that simple loop:

- First of all, we need to select the input *relative* to our complexity function will be computed. That case is pretty trivial: the variable is the size of the array. That's because we want to know how our program act respect the growing of the size of the input array.
- The loop will be repeat `SIZE_ARRAY` times. So number of times the body will be executed is `SIZE_ARRAY` times (note: that values is variable, is not constant value).
- Now consider the loop body. The instruction `array[i] = i` does not depend on how big is the array. It takes an unknown number of CPU cycles, but that number is always the same, that is *constant*.

Summarizing, we repeat `SIZE_ARRAY` times an instruction which takes a constant number of CPU clocks (let's say `k` is that value, is constant).

So, mathematically the number of CPU clocks will be executed for that simple program will be `SIZE_ARRAY * k`.

With the [O Big notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) we can describe the limiting behaviour. That is the behaviour a function will assume when the independent variable goes to infinity.

We can write:

```
O(SIZE_ARRAY * k) = O(SIZE_ARRAY)
```

That's because `k` is a constant value and by definition of *Big O Notation* the constant does not grown at infinity (is constant ever).

If we call `SIZE_ARRAY` as `N` (the size of the input) we can say that our function is a `O(N)` in time complexity.

---

The last ("more complicate") example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_ARRAY; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_ARRAY; ++j) {
    array[j] += j; 
  }
}
```

As before our problem size is compared to the `SIZE_ARRAY`.

Shortly:

- The first cycle will be execute `SIZE_ARRAY` times, that is `O(SIZE_ARRAY)`.
- The second cycle will be execute `SIZE_ARRAY` times.
- The body of the second cycle is an instruction which will take a constant number of CPU cycle, let's say that number is `k`.

We take the number of time the first loop will be executed and we multiply it by its body complexity.

```
O(SIZE_ARRAY) * [first_loop_body_complexity].
```

But the body of the first loop is:

```
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_ARRAY; ++j) {
    array[j] += j; 
}
```

Which is a single loop as the previous example, and we've just computed is complexity. It is an `O(SIZE_ARRAY)`. So we can see that:

```
[first_loop_body_complexity] = O(SIZE_ARRAY)
```

Finally, our entire complexity is:

```
O(SIZE_ARRAY) * O(SIZE_ARRAY) = O(SIZE_ARRAY * SIZE_ARRAY)
```

That is

```
O(SIZE_ARRAY^2)
```

Using `N` instead of `SIZE_ARRAY`.

```
O(N^2)
```

Comment: The choices are a) theta(n^2), b) theta ((nlog2n)^2), c) theta(n(log2n)^3), d) theta (n^3log2n), and e) theta(n^4). I know that option e is wrong. Would it be (d) since it is seems like it would be the closest bounds to O(n^4)?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is not a mathematical explication. It's a dumb down version which I think can help someone who is introduced to the world of complexities and is as clueless as I was when I first met this concept. Also I don't give you the answers. Just try to help you get there.

---

Moral of the story: don't count steps. Complexity is not about how many  instructions (I will use this instead of "steps") are executed. That in itself is (almost) completely irelevant. In layman terms (time) complexity is about how does the execution time grow depending on how the input grows - that's how I finally understood complexity.

Let's take it step by step with some of the most encountered complexity:

#### constant complexity: O(1)

this represents an algorithm whose execution time does not depend on the input. The execution time doesn't grow when the input grows.

For instance:

```
auto foo_o1(int n) {
   instr 1;
   instr 2;
   instr 3;
   if (n > 20) {
      instr 4;
      instr 5;
      instr 6;
   }
   instr 7;
   instr 8;
};
```

The execution time of this function doesn't depend on the value of `n`. Notice how I can say that even if some instructions get executed or not depending on the value of `n`. Mathematically this is because `O(constant) == O(1)`. Intuitively it's because the growth of the number of instructions it's not proportional with `n`. In the same ideea, it's irrelevant if the function has 10 instr or 1k instructions. It's still `O(1)` - constant complexity.

#### Linear complexity: O(n)

this represents an algorithm whose execution time is proportional with the input. When given a small input it takes a certain amount. When increasing the input the execution time grows proportionally:

```
auto foo1_on(int n)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      instr;
}
```

This function is `O(n)`. This means that when the input doubles, the execution time grows by a factor. This is true for any input. E.g when you double the input from 10 to 20 and when you double the input from 1000 to 2000 there is more or less the same factor in the growth of the execution time of the algorithm.

In line with the ideea of ignoring what doesn't contribute much **comparatively** with the "fastest" growth, all the next functions still have O(n) complexity. Mathematically `O` complexities are upper-bounded. This leads to `O(c1*n + c0) = O(n)`

```
auto foo2_on(int n)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
      instr;
}
```

here: `O(n / 2) = O(n)`

```
auto foo3_on(int n)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     instr 1;
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     instr 2;
}
```

here `O(n) + O(n) = O(2*n) = O(n)`

#### polynomial order 2 complexity: O(n^2)

This tells you that as you grow the input, the execution time grows by factor bigger and bigger. For instance the next is a valid behavior of an `O(n^2)` algorithm:

Read: When you double the input from .. to .. you could get an increase of execution time of .. times

- from 100 to 200 : 1.5 times
- from 200 to 400 : 1.8 times
- from 400 to 800 : 2.2 times
- from 800 to 1600 : 6 times
- from 1600 to 3200 : 500 times

**Try this!**. Write an `O(n^2)` algorithm. And double the input. At first you will see small increases of computation time. At one time it just *blows* and you have to wait few minutes when at the previous steps it just took mere seconds.

This can be easily understand once you look over a `n^2` graph.

```
auto foo_on2(int n)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
         instr;
}
```

How is this function `O(n)`? Simple: first loop executes `n` times. (I don't care if it's `n times plus 3` or `4*n`. Then, for each step of the first loop the second loop executes `n` times. There are `n` iterations of the i loop. For each i iteration there are `n` j iterations. So in total we have `n * n = n^2` j iterations. Thus `O(n^2)`

There are other interesting complexities like logarithmic, exponential etc etc. Once you understand the concept behind the math, it gets very interesting. For instance a logarithmic complexity `O(log(n))` has an execution time that grows *slower* and *slower* as the input grows. You can clearly see that when you look over a log graph.

There are a lot of resources on the net about complexities. Search. Read. Don't understand! Search again. Read. Take paper and pen. Understand!. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In these simple cases you can determine time complexity by finding the instruction that is executed most often and then find out how this number depends on `n`.

In example 1, `count++` is executed n^4 times => O(n^4)

In example 2, `sum += i;` is executed n times => O(n)

In examples 3, `sum ++;` is executed n^2 times => O(n^2)

Well, actually that is not correct because some of your loops are executed n+1 times, but that doesn't matter at all. In example 1, the instruction is actually executed (n+1)^2*n^2 times which is the same as n^4 + 2 n^3 + n^2. For time complexity only the largest power counts.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple:

O(N) means **less than or equal** to N. Therefore, and within a one code snippet, we ignore all and focus on the code that takes the highest number of steps (Highest power) to solve the problem / finish the execution.

Following your examples:

```
int function (int n){
   int count = 0;                              // ignore

   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // This looks interesting
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)              // This looks interesting
         for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)           // This looks interesting
            for (int m = 0; m <= n; m++)       // This looks interesting
               count++;                        // This is what we are looking for. 

  return count;                                // ignore
}
```

For that statement to finish we will need to "wait" or "cover" or "step" (n + 1) * n * n * (n + 1) => O(~N^4).

Second example:

```
int func1 (int n){
       int sum = 0;                                // ignore

       for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // This looks interesting
          sum += i;                                // This is what we are looking for. 

       return sum;                                 // ignore
}
```

For that to finish it needs n + 1 steps => O(~n).

Third example:

```
int func2 (int n){
           int sum = 0;                                // ignore

           for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)                // This looks interesting
              for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)             // This looks interesting
                  sum ++;                              // This is what we are looking for. 

           for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)                // ignore
               sum--;                                  // ignore

           return sum;                                 // ignore
    }
```

For that to finish we will need (n + 1) * (n + 1) steps => O(~N^2)